# Ionic 2: push notification on click

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, ionic2

A notification appears, but upon clicking them, they only open the application again. What I want is upon clicking the notification, it opens a specific item.

In Laravel, I am using the [brozot/Laravel-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) package for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications, and on the other end, I'm using [Ionic push notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) to receive and display notifications in the notification tray.

If I don't use `setClickAction()` on Laravel, the Ionic application opens upon clicking the notification, but if I set `setClickAction()`, then nothing happens. The notification merely disappears.

**Laravel-code**:

```
$notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder('my title');
$notificationBuilder->setBody('Hello world')
                    ->setSound('default')
                    ->setClickAction('window.doSomething');
$notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
```

**Ionic 2 framework sample**:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, MenuController, ModalController, Events, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import {
    SearchPage
} from '../pages/pages';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

    rootPage: any = SearchPage;

    constructor(
        platform: Platform,
        statusBar: StatusBar,
        splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private menu: MenuController,
        private modalCtrl: ModalController,
        private events: Events,
        private push: Push,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });
        this.pushSetup();
    }

    pushSetup() {
        const options: PushOptions = {
            android: {
                senderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                forceShow: true
            },
            ios: {
                senderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                alert: 'true',
                badge: true,
                sound: 'true'
            },
            windows: {},
            browser: {
                pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
            }
        };

        const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

        pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {

        });

        pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
            alert(registration.id);
        });

        pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => alert('Error with Push plugin' + error));

    }

}

(<any>window).doSomething = function () {
    alert('doSomething called'); 
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i implemented the same functionality in Ionic with One-Signal and firebase (both are free ) . if you are willing to change plugin will provide it as answer

Comment: Yes please, i am willing

Comment: please check my solution

Comment: You should catch your notification within the pushObject.on('notification'), that is where you could navigate to the designated page.

Answer (score 0):

There are  these steps that need to be done for general One-Signal push notification to be implemented

1. Create a [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) Account
2. Add a New APP in the One Signal , configure for Android first (you can target for any platform but i'm focussing on Android as of now) .you need to get the Google Server Key and Google Project Id.
3. You can get the Above keys from the Firebase using [this](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key) Steps
4. Now we are done with Configuring the OneSignal Account, now integrate with the  [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/) using the [cordova plugin](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK)

**In Ionic2** :

```
 OneSignal.startInit(//google Server Key, //Google ProjectId);
            OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
            OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
            OneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
                // handle received here how you wish.


                // this.goToReleatedPage(data.Key, data.Value);
            });
            OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data: any) => {
                //console.log('MyData'+ JSON.stringify(data.additionalData));
                this.parseObject(data);
            });

            OneSignal.endInit();
```

**ParsingObject in Ionic**

```
public parseObject(obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            this.goToReleatedPage(key, obj[key]);
            if (obj[key] instanceof Object) {
                this.parseObject(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

**goToReleatedPage Method**

```
public goToReleatedPage(Key, Value) {
        //console.log("Pagename"+" " + Key + "ID" +" " + Value);
        if (Key === 'xxxx') {
            this.navCtrl.push(xxxPage, {
                id: Value
            });
        } else if (Key === 'Foo') {
            this.navCtrl.push(foosPage, {
                id: Value,

            });
        } else if (Key === 'bar') {
            this.navCtrl.push(barPage, {
                id: Value
            });
        }

    }
```

While sending the Message from `OneSignal` , you need to specify which `page` you need to open and you want to pass `Id` as follows

[image]